# Update if table have a row with 2 similar column, insert instead

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time understanding the use of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, let's say that I have a `tracks` table with the following columns:

```
id    tracklist_id    number    name

1          1            1       Track1
2          1            2       Track2
3          1            3       Track3
4          2            1       Track1
5          2            2       Track2
6          2            3       Track3
```

If there's already a track n°1 defined for the tracklist 1 (like in the example) then just `UPDATE` the `name` of it, if not then `INSERT` it. I tried something like that:

```
INSERT INTO tracks (number, name, tracklist_id) VALUES ('1', 'Track1', '1'), ('2', 'Track2', '1'), ('3', 'Track3', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name);
```

I believe that my problem is related to the `PRIMARY KEY`, I tried without success to define `tracklist_id` as the primary key, without success because it's present multiple times in the table (this is the part I'm not sure I understood at all).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only works for UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY, and in your case  `tracklist_id` can't be, because you have repeated values there on that column.

Comment: you will need a composite primary key or unique together key for the tracklist_id and number

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez Rodriguez Thank you for your answer, then what would be a good solution to only update a track that already exists? In the current state of my project I delete every tracks related to the tracklist then "reconstruct" completly the list every time, I feel like this is a very bad way of doing things and there's probably more efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: @e4c5 I tried making a composite key using `ALTER TABLE tracks
ADD CONSTRAINT tk_number PRIMARY KEY (album_id, number);` but I get the `#1062 - Duplicate entry '0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'` error, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem here is that your data is already inconsistent. There is nothing wrong with your query.  THere are plenty of Q&As here that show how they can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alter to a UNIQUE composite

```
ALTER TABLE `tracks` ADD UNIQUE `trkid_number` (`tracklist_id`,`number`);
```